# Animate Pie chat with new data push through API in Angular 8

Tags: angular, d3.js

How can I animate the Pie chart with new push through subscribe API values.

Following is the data, I have right now.

```
samples: PieGraph[] = [
    { name: "Emirates", v1: 202921689.73000002, v2:235698755  },
    { name: "DHL", v1: 32839771.62,  v2:235698755 },
  ];
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvzqdv)

I only want to show `name` and `v1`
Once this v1 values change `d3` pie animate.

Right now I add the static data in the example.

Comment: what you mean by animate? do you want dynamic data for your pie chart?

Comment: yes I have dynamic data fetching from API

Comment: and animation like this [link](https://bl.ocks.org/adamjanes/53eedf0b915fd8b20f04fd08bc24ff00)

Answer (score 0):

Logic:

1. Make HTTP call to your API to get data
2. On Change of Radio button values send selected value to component and load data accordingly and draw Chart again

Use below link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hx8jbn